# Methodology of Estimating Economic Costs?

Tags: econometrics, markets, empirical-methods, methodology

To be specific, I am currently devising an honours thesis proposal to estimate the effects of a lack of competition in consumer electronic repair markets on variables such as firm profits, consumer social welfare, and environmental outcomes.

The issue is, I am not sure of the methodology of doing so (I am an undergrad so excuse my lack of technical knowledge). I would presume I need data on my choice variables in an environment with a competitive repair market, and then take the difference to quantify the cost. However, is this possible without a suitable example of a competitive repair market (eg. for iphone repairs)?